# Retrieve saved (hidden) SSH password from PhpStorm 2017.1

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

I have forgotten SSH password from Remote Server, but it is saved in IDE (PhpStorm 2017.1) in hidden way:

[image: PhpStorm 2017.1.4 ssh config]

Is there any way to view hidden password?

Comment: It depends on your OS and password storage (I guess). What option do you have selected  at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`? If it's KeePass -- then you should be able to open that `c.kdbx` file in appropriate program (there are many for each OS). If it's Keychain (Mac OS / Linux) then I have no idea (not a Mac/Linux user myself).

Comment: @LazyOne  Yes, passwords in KeePass. But I tried to open it in "KeePass 2": it shows a modal pop-up with master-password, key-file etc  [screenshot](http://screenshot.ru/ba2d2c70b2ee317b87520d73b0a8328a.png). Of cause I do not know these information...

Comment: Try with no password at all (that's if you have not setup Master Password in PhpStorm). Otherwise -- if it's not your PhpStorm setup .. or you have forgot that password as well -- no use.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170108 -- try doing what it says here (official comment from corresponding dev)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally could retrieve password from PhpStorm 2017.1:

1. Go to *Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords*, enter new master password and save.
2. Open */.PhpStorm2017.1/config/c.kdbx* (in "Keepass 2" or "Keeweb") with saved master password.
3. Here it is!

Thanks to @LazyOne

Comment: If you enter a new master password, the old passwords will be cleared (PhpStorm 2019.3.2)

Comment: I just entered a master password, and was able to use it from keepass2 (Intellij IDEA 2021.1). Maybe you already had it secured with a master password? In that case changing it, without knowing the old one will indeed clear the password-db.

Comment: works flawlessly!